# Is it true that any finite module over a DVR has finite length?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My algebraic geometry professor seemed to use that on a nonsingular algebraic curve $X$ defined over a field $k$, and for any closed point $x\in X$, we have that  $$\operatorname{length}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\Omega_{X/k})_x<\infty$$ and since $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ is a DVR and $\Omega_{X/k}$ a coherent sheaf, he seemed to be assuming that any finite module over a DVR has finite length. Is this true?

Comment: I don't think that if $R$ is a DVR then $R$ has finite length as $R$-module, unless by finite you really mean finite and not finitely generated as usual.

Comment: This may be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain

Comment: Is there any reason why it's true that $$\operatorname{length}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\Omega_{X/k})_x<\infty$$ in this case?

Comment: $\Omega_{X/k}$ is a locally free sheaf on the nonsingular locus of the variety $X$, and it's rank at a point is the dimension of $X$ at that point. Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: But then don't we just have the problem where the length of a DVR over itself is infinite?

Comment: To be clear: It just plain wrong that the length of a DVR is finite. since powers of the uniformizing element give an infinite chain of submodules. You say that your professor "seemed to use" that fact, so you probably missed something there.